# unable to decode json variable in corona sdk which i encoded in php

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
local URL = "http://localhost:8080/corona/send.php?email=" .. sender .. "&sendto=" .. sendto .. "&message=" .. message;
            --local URL="http://localhost:8080/corona/fetch.php?usr="..namee
            local response = http.request(URL)
    if response == nil then
    print("No Dice")
    else
    local data=json.decode(response)
    print ("something ----:"..data[1]);--This part gives error
```

Comment: Php code:  $output=array();
          $output[0]="success";
          echo json_encode($output);

Comment: Try check what you get in `response` like that `x = json.decode(response);for k,v in pairs(x) do print(k..":"..v)end`